# Laravel 8 auth not getting the CSS online but on localhost it's working

Tags: css, laravel-8

Good Day to You!

I am using Laravel 8 auth, running the following:

```
laravel new e_shop --jet --stack=livewire
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"
npm install & npm run dev
php artisan migrate
```

on localhost, everything is working fine, but the online CSS register & login not working. :(
Here is the website location: http://www.gardoweb.com/e-shop
If&when you click on *login*, you see my problem.
Before I put online Laravel8 app I run the following, but it does not help:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

I deleted the bootstrap CACHE content.
In the public folder there are these files:

e_shop\public\css\apps.css
e_shop\public\js\apps.js

It was compiled with webmix.

e_shop\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php the declaration as follows:
in the head ->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
 <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

So that's all, I don't know what to do next, I am on godaddy.
Thank you for your response, good day!